# Error in attaching a database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I detach a database file from a SQL Server 2000 and try to attach it in SQL Server 2008 By the following code:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [KARGAR] ON 
( FILENAME = N'F:\1111\KARGAR_Data.MDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'F:\1111\KARGAR_Log.LDF' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

When I try to run above code, I see the following error:

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
>   Unable to open the physical file
>   "F:\1111\KARGAR_Data.MDF". Operating
>   system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve
>   text for this error. Reason: 15105)".

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thoughts:

- Can SQL Server see the F: drive?
- It has permissions there?
- This is a local drive? SQL Server does not support network drives for databases normally

Note: the SQL Server engine runs under a service account that requires permissions on the relevant folders

Comment: @hosseinsinohe: "local" on your PC, or "local" on the SQL Server machine??

Comment: @hosseinsinohe: the files **must** be on the SQL Server machine - **not** your local PC. The SQL server **cannot** reach your local drives (assuming your local PC and the server machine where you're attaching this aren't the same machine, of course)

Answer (score 2):

another way check you open management studio by user has permission